# Footer doesn't stay in place (React-Gatsby)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Why my damn footer won't stay at the bottom of the page?

```js
import React from "react"

import Navbar from "./navbar"
import Footer from "./footer"
import Sidebar from "./sidebar"

import "./layoutplus.css"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
        <div className="main-cont">
          <main id="main-post" className="main-post">{children}</main>

          <Sidebar id="sidebar" className="sidebar"/>
        </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout





import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'gatsby'

import {FaFacebook, FaTwitter, FaInstagram} from 'react-icons/fa'

export default function Footer() {
    return (
      <div id="footer" className="footer">
        <div className="footer-middle">
          <ul>
            <li><Link className="footer-link" to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link className="footer-link" to="/guides">Guides</Link></li>
            <li><Link className="footer-link" to="/about">About</Link></li>
          </ul>

          <div className="footer-bottom">
            <ul className="footer-ul">
              <li><Link to="//" ><FaFacebook className="footer-dot" /></Link></li>
              <li><Link to="//"><FaTwitter className="footer-dot" /></Link></li>
              <li><Link to="//"><FaInstagram className="footer-dot"/></Link></li>
            </ul>

            <p>Build with <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#663399" }} to="https://www.gatsbyjs.com/">Gatsby</Link>.</p>
            <p>&copy;{new Date().getFullYear()} <Link className="footer-link" to="/about">blablabla</Link> - All Rights Reserved</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

```css
/*MAIN CONT*/
.main-cont {
  max-width: 1344px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 4.5fr 1.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "main-post test-ads"
    "main-post test-hottopic";
  padding-top: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .main-cont {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "main-post"
      "test-ads"
      "test-hottopic";
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}

.main-post {
  grid-area: main-post;
}

.test-ads {
  grid-area: test-ads;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;

  text-align: center;
}

.test-hottopic {
  grid-area: test-hottopic;
  border: 1px solid red;

  text-align: center;
}


/*FOOTER*/
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: var(--bgGray);
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-middle {
  color: var(--mainWithe);
}

.footer-middle ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: var(--mainWhite);
  padding: 0rem 2px;
}

.footer-middle li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

.footer-bottom {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.footer-link {
  color: var(--offWhite);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-link:hover {
  color: var(--mainOrange);
}

.footer-ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

.footer-dot {
  color: var(--offWhite);
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
}

.footer-dot:hover {
  transition: var(--mainTransition);
  color: var(--mainOrange);
}
```

The footer seems to stay at the bottom of the screen always, but never at the end of the page. I don't know why, this problem starts when I added the grid to the .main-cont container, because I need a grid nested into the body.
Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Please provide a working demo link of your problem on codesandbox.io or codepen.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gatsby, you should struck the brain a little bit, since it's not that easy to access the wrappers of the content, but of course, it doable.

Taking your `<Layout>` as an example:

```
import React from "react"

import Navbar from "./navbar"
import Footer from "./footer"
import Sidebar from "./sidebar"

import "./layoutplus.css"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
        <div className="main-cont">
          <main id="main-post" className="main-post">{children}</main>

          <Sidebar id="sidebar" className="sidebar"/>
        </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

Using the previous structure, you can't access the wrapper of your components because Gatsby wraps it between an unreachable `<div>` with an empty class. However, what you can do is to wrap it again within a known class element, such as:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <section className="site-wrapper">
      <Navbar />
        <div className="main-cont">
          <main id="main-post" className="main-post">{children}</main>

          <Sidebar id="sidebar" className="sidebar"/>
        </div>
      <Footer />
    </section>
  )
}
```

Given that `site-wrapper` class you can add the following CSS:

```
.site-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main  {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Basically, you are telling the wrapper (`site-wrapper`) to expand until filling the viewport (`100vh`). Since your `main` tag (change it to the desired class if needed) can grow free (`flex-grow: 1`) so your footer will be always at the bottom of the page because it's pushed by the rest of the flexbox column.

[Flexbox](https://caniuse.com/?search=flex) has better acceptance/fallback within old browsers than [grid](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid) has, but you can achieve it either way, the idea is always to push (or let the `main` grow) the footer at the bottom without depending on the content above, using some [`minmax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax()) should do the trick using a grid-based approach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanatory answer! unfortunately the footer is still looks like at z-index: 1 and shown on top of the main content of the page. I will try to clean my css and see if this method works

Comment: Just clean part of my css and seems it works! I'm gonna clean the rest of it and hope it still work! thank you so much!